# ES6 (React) - self invoking functions?

Tags: reactjs, function, ecmascript-6, redux

could someone explain the code below to me? I understand what it does but the syntax is odd, what does it accomplish?

When I have:

```
export default ComponentName;
```

it's easy, but this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);
```

What does it exactly do? Is it ES6-ish syntax? It looks like self invoked function with an argument, but how does these arguments work? The part I have trouble understanding is:

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);
```

The first part `connect(mapStateToProps)` is easy - it's just a `connect` function with `mapStateToProps` as an argument, but what's the deal with `(ComponentName)`? Why do we export self-invoking function? Why do we have to pass component name here?

Comment: `connect` is a curried function. Search for "currying" in functional programming, the tl;dr is that instead of taking several arguments in one function and returning a value, you take one argument at a time and return a function that takes another argument, and so on, and only return the value on the last function on the chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically wrapping a component inside a **Higher-Order Component**.

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html):

> A higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component.

When you invoke `connect(mapStateToProps)` it returns a function. That function accepts a component as an argument and returns a new component, which is just the same component you passed to it except the new component will now contain the data from the Redux store.

So by appending `(ComponentName)` i.e. `connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName)`, you are not actually exporting a function, you are invoking a function and exporting what it returns which is a new component.

Answer (score 2):

`connect()` is function that return a function which takes component as argument

it just like this

```
let f = connect(mapStateToProps); // f is function now
f(ComponentName)
```

see this example to illustrate the idea

```js
function foo(a){
    return function(b){
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
    }
}

foo(1)(2);

//or

let f = foo(1);
f(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`connect` is a higher order component. 
It has a structure to the one given below: A function that returns another function.

```js
function add(first) {
  return function(second) {
    return first+second;
  }
}

const result = add(4)(5);
console.log(result);
```

It might be easier for you to understand like this:

```
const reduxFn = connect(mapStateToProps);
reduxFn(Component);
```